# Getting python clicks from host to register in Virtual Machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

Im working on some scripts that I need to run on top of a VM.  I'm using VMWare Workstation 15 Pro.  The test script I ran to see if this would work is:

```
def main():
    time.sleep(5)
    pydirectinput.click()
```

The clicks on the virtual machine don't register while the clicks on the host system do.  Is there a way to get the clicks to register on the VM and how?

Comment: This may be a stupid comment/question, but just to be sure.. Does the initial click only gain the VM window focus? You may potentially need to gain focus, then perform the click(s)..?

Comment: Ive only tested it with the window as the foreground window.

Answer (score 2):

This may be impossible to achieve as even the people in the VMWare community have no advice.

A virtual machine normally communicates to the mouse on a lower level than normal programs. You see this for example if you don't install the VMWare Tools in the guest system. If you want to work with such a virtual machine, the machine machine seems to actually conquer the mouse. You cannot even get the mouse back. This is because VMWare or VirtualBox do not use the mouse in a regular way. This is still the case if you have installed the VMWare Tools. But then it is only a bit more comfortable for the user.

Probably this very specific mechanism is the reason why pydirectinput cannot inject mouse controls into the virtual machine. Indeet it is known that pydirectinput does not work with all sorts of programs.

## Over the network solution

That been said, you need another solution. There are two ideas.

If you can install and run something on the virtual machine, a simple server client approach may help you. In Python this is really simple. The idea is to send python commands as strings directly into the virtual machine and execute them there.

See the following example. In the virtual machine you must have this running:

```
import socket
import pydirectinput

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65433

def vm_exec(command):
    exec(command)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        request_line = "" 
        while True:
            received = conn.recv(1).decode('utf-8')
            if received == ';':
                vm_exec(request_line)
                request_line = ""
            else:
                request_line += received
```

And then you can use pydirectinput from the host machine in this way:

```
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65433

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

def moveTo(x,y):
    s.sendall(bytes("pydirectinput.moveTo({},{});".format(x,y), 'utf-8'))
def click():
    s.sendall(bytes("pydirectinput.click();", 'utf-8'))

moveTo(100,200)
click()
```

You must change the IP address to something that works for you. The address 127.0.0.1 definitively does not. This is only for testing purposes.

This solution has a great advantage that you don't have to keep the virtual machine window open. You can minimize it and still control the machine.

Of course, this solution creates a huge security problem if you use an IP address that is not only visible by the host. Obviously everybody who connects to the server, can execute arbitrary commands.

There are libraries for python that implement the mechanism for you. The function is called Remote-Method-Invocation. You'll find plenty of information about this. You can even mix programming languages (e.g. use Python on the client and C on the server). But as I demonstrated you, the principle is very simple in Python (because Python is an interpreted language), so that you actually don't need extra libraries.

## Over remote console solution

An alternative solution is to use the VNC or RDP server of VMWare to control the virtual machine. This does not require the installation of extra software on the virtual machine and will also work during the installation of the guest operating system. With this approach you actually have to have the virtual machine window in the VNC viewer open and visible in the foreground. But according to your question this is what you want.

In VMWare the option to enable this is Virtual Machine Settings -> Options -> VNC Connections. And then you can use your favourite VNC software.

Comment: I appreciate your input.  Unfortunately the code you suggested defeats the purpose of this evolution - not running scripts on the virtual machine to click\key.  I may have to mess around using some sort of remote desktop I guess.

Comment: Then the VNC solution still works.